# Can we set laravel enum column to be unique

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Can enum column be unique?

I have 5 different currencies in my table and only one of them has to be default, can i set unique for that column?

```
$table->enum('default_currency', ['yes', 'no'])->unique();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do using `UNIQUE INDEX`. It will work for two rows, but in the third row it will fail, since the valid values are just two.

You need to manually do this logic, and you can do it in many places. I personally like to do this kind of logic in a [model observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers), so you can watch the `saving` event. The logic is this:

1. Something try to save the currency (create or update)
2. The model observer will catch the saving event
3. If the `default_currency` is set to true, you do some query like this: `Currency::whereDefaultCurrency(true)->update(["default_currency"=>false])`

Thia way, you will always have one single currency with `default_currency` set to `true`.

Example of `CurrencyObserver`:

```
class CurrencyObserver {
    public function saving(Currency $currency) {
        if ($currency->isDirty('default_currency') && $currency->default_currency) {
            Currency::where('default_currency', true)->update(['default_currency' => false]);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. There's some tricks to do. You should do this in the `saving` method (combines both updating and creating in a single hook, that happen before the save occurs on database), and you should only do that update IF the default_currency was updated to true. I'll update my answer to provide an example, but I'm on mobile, so some typing erros can occur.

Comment: I'm getting this error currently `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Api\Admin\save()` i don't think it's related to your answer but it definitely holds my test back. I will get back to you will result once I've fixed this error, thank you

Comment: Probably not related to this. The error message contains the line and file that the error occurs, show any related code so I can try to help

Comment: here is my latest observe file code  http://collabedit.com/2c78r

Comment: Hi, the error I've mentioned before already solved it was typo issue in controller but  based on my code that i shared before http://collabedit.com/2c78r when i save my new currency it won't save at all while i have the value sent to controller `database screenshot` https://ibb.co/vYmNnWM and `network screenshot` https://ibb.co/gz22q7R

Comment: here is another screenshot that explains the issue that observe (probably) cause better https://prnt.sc/qt8yrw

Comment: Ok the issue with my `observe (probably) cause` was because you were using `true and false` while my value is enum of `yes and no` so with editing that it now changes my previous currency default column to `no` BUT it also sets my newly added currency to `no` as well. (in other word: i have all my currencies set no as default, so there is no default currency :) )

Comment: well well well, after long time fighting with it i've found the problem :) it was function naming in observe file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924143/edit-rows-with-laravel-observe , Thank you for your idea and helps