# Edit rows with laravel observe

Tags: php, laravel

I have `currencies` table where only one of them has to be set as `default_currency`, I've been suggested to use observe method in order to set previous `default_currency` to `no` when i add new `default_currency`

#### Current data

[image: one]

## Issues

1. The issue with my observe is when i save new data and set
   `default_currency` to `yes` not only old `default_currency` gets set
   to `no` but also new one
2. Anther issue is if i save new currency and even not set `default_currency` value of it to `yes` still it edits `default_currency` of other row to `no`

#### Result

[image: two]

## Code

`Observe`

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Currency;

class CurrencyObserver
{
    public function created(Currency $currency)
    {
        if ($currency->isDirty('default_currency') && $currency->default_currency) {
            Currency::where('default_currency', 'yes')->update(['default_currency' => 'no']);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function updated(Currency $currency)
    {
        if ($currency->isDirty('default_currency') && $currency->default_currency) {
            Currency::where('default_currency', 'yes')->update(['default_currency' => 'no']);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function deleted(Currency $currency)
    {
        //
    }

    public function restored(Currency $currency)
    {
        //
    }

    public function forceDeleted(Currency $currency)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|unique:currencies',
            'symbol' => 'required|unique:currencies',
            'position' => 'required',
            'decimal_point' => 'required',
            'separator_point' => 'required',
            'decimals' => 'required',
            'default_currency' => 'required', //won't save!
        ]);

        $currency = new Currency;
        $currency->name = $request->input('name');
        $currency->symbol = $request->input('symbol');
        $currency->position = $request->input('position');
        $currency->decimal_point = $request->input('decimal_point');
        $currency->separator_point = $request->input('separator_point');
        $currency->decimals = $request->input('decimals');
        $currency->default_currency = $request->input('default_currency');
        $currency->save();

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $currency,
            'success' => 'Your currency saved successfully.'
        ]);
    }
```

### What I want

1. Set old row `default_currency` to `no`, if new row has input data of `default_currency` as `yes` otherwise just let old one be `yes`

**Any idea how to fix this issue?**

Comment: You should strongly consider using a `boolean` column instead of a `string` one here.

Comment: @ceejayoz it was function naming issue :)

Comment: My comment is separate from the issue, though. If you've got a `yes/no` situation you should use a boolean column type, not a string.

Comment: @ceejayoz appreciate your suggestion, as you said it's a `should` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

My problem was caused by function naming in observe file. As you can see my default created file came with `public function created(Currency $currency)` which was updating my database after save process is done, therefore both my `default_currency`'s would be set to `no` :)

I've changed my function name to `public function saving(Currency $currency)` form `created` to `saving` therefore this function happens during saving process and not after it.

Also to avoid issue with next data which their `default_currency` is set to `no` and not updating current currency i've placed my code inside if condition.

## final code

```
public function saving(Currency $currency)
    {
        if($currency->default_currency == 'yes'){
            if ($currency->isDirty('default_currency') && $currency->default_currency) {
                Currency::where('default_currency', 'yes')->update(['default_currency' => 'no']);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope it help others as well.

Comment: Remove return line. Observer method should return void.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```php
public function creating(Currency $currency)
{
    if ($currency->isDirty('default_currency') && $currency->default_currency === 'yes') {
        Currency::where('default_currency', 'yes')->update(['default_currency' => 'no']);
    }
}

public function updating(Currency $currency)
{
    if ($currency->isDirty('default_currency') && $currency->default_currency === 'yes') {
        Currency::where('default_currency', 'yes')->update(['default_currency' => 'no']);
    }
}
```

Here I changed the `updated` and `created` to `updating` and `creating`. The former two execute **after** the row has been updated/created and with the logic inside it sets all currencies to default = 'no'. However, if you do the same before the new default currency is set, the new currency will not be effected by the query.

Also, your 2nd part of the `if` check (`$currency->default_currency`) will always return true since both `yes` and `no` are truthy values, so I changed that to string comparison instead.

Comment: exactly, I've just shared similar solution as yours :)

Comment: Yeah, just saw. `saving()` is nicer indeed since you don't need the duplicate code!